# Html editor - Text to HTML convertor

Tags: html-editor, text-to-html

I want to convert my text into HTML format, it would be just like this: that I just copy paste the text from word, pdf [with formatting & colors] to the editor and it will convert it into HTML tags, so that when I decode it again it would give me the same format that I have pasted.

I am mostly happy with PageBreeze but sometimes it destroys the formatting.

Are there any other editor suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I think it's a crude solution, you can try using the on-the-fly generated comment below, highlight, view source and copy it or pretty much any of the Rich Text Editor Javascript plugins out there such as [RTE](http://batiste.dosimple.ch/blog/posts/2007-09-11-1/rich-text-editor-jquery.html), the simplest I could find. (I'm not sure if those preserves copy-pasted formatting)

However, you won't be assured that any formatting (font/color) you get from here will be carried over to your website. In addition to HTML, CSS plays a huge part in styling, especially text-color, highlighting, spacing, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think in word you can do file >saveas > html

However it's going to be junky and nasty.

Your best option is to learn basic HTML (it really is super easy) and manually do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks tom, I do have a idea about HTML, but I have a some post that I have to put on website, for the same reason I am first converting all the text into HTML and then when rendering converting it into proper formatted text.